# unable to download code from server.Unable to open this internet site.The requested site is either unavailable

Tags: c#

I am not here to get a solution to the problem.I wanted to know the root cause for this issue.Because we rolled out our application worldwide and when users are clicking on some download button they are facing with the error.
And can it be solved from the code either from the client or from the server.
Now i am testing by marking the Friendly http errors( yes/no) if i am keeping this option as No then this issue is coming up and the vice versa.

So please help me whether it can be solved from the server side or i dont know what exactly happening from the code side.Do i have to look for some http status code or something?
Confused
Please help?
Emphasizing that i dont need a solution and i only need the root cause and whether it can be solved once in for all.
Thanks in advance

Comment: A LOT of context is missing here. You'll need to explain your problem much more clearly. There's a `C#` tag only. Not even what base technology is involved is clear.

Comment: the code written in C#.When i tried to download some content from the application it throws me the error that was mentioned.

Comment: Post the code that's failing, then. Otherwise, who can tell what's happening?

Comment: I cant do that..But i can attach the error screenshot that i am facing.